# How to render videos url in a template page using Video Embed field?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, files

I have done some research on how I can render on a node .tpl page a youtube video, but couldn't find a solution.
The module I am using is [Video Embed field](https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field) and Drupal version is Drupal 7.

When doing a print-r content I can see a list of values but I'm unsure on how I can use them to show my video.

Here is the code

```
 [field_video_url] => Array
                    (
                        [und] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [video_url] => http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dS4JR0BbKO8
                                        [thumbnail_path] => public://video_embed_field_thumbnails/youtube/dS4JR0BbKO8.jpg
                                        [video_data] => a:21:{s:5:"xmlns";s:27:"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";s:11:"xmlns$media";s:29:"http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";s:8:"xmlns$gd";s:32:
                                        [embed_code] => 
                                        [description] => 
                                    )

                            )

                    )
[#formatter] => video_embed_field
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [#theme] => video_embed_field_embed_code
                        [#url] => http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dS4JR0BbKO8
                        [#style] => normal
                        [#video_data] => Array
                            (
                                [xmlns] => http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
                                [xmlns$media] => http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/
                                [xmlns$gd] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005
                                [xmlns$yt] => http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007
                                [gd$etag] => W/"CUACRn47eCp7I2A9XRZbFU8."
                                [id] => tag:youtube.com,2008:video:dS4JR0BbKO8
                                [published] => 2011-12-12T08:23:43.000Z
                                [updated] => 2014-08-20T08:36:07.000Z
                                [category] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [scheme] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind
                                                [term] => http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [scheme] => http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat
                                                [term] => Tech
                                                [label] => Science & Technology
                                            )

                                    )

                                [title] => Introduction to Theming Basics for Drupal 7
                                [content] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => application/x-shockwave-flash
                                        [src] => http://www.youtube.com/v/dS4JR0BbKO8?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata
                                    )

                                [link] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [rel] => alternate
                                                [type] => text/html
                                                [href] => http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dS4JR0BbKO8&feature=youtube_gdata
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [rel] => http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.related
                                                [type] => application/atom+xml
                                                [href] => http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/dS4JR0BbKO8/related?v=2
                                            )

                                        [2] => Array
                                            (
                                                [rel] => http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#mobile
                                                [type] => text/html
                                                [href] => http://m.youtube.com/details?v=dS4JR0BbKO8
                                            )

                                        [3] => Array
                                            (
                                                [rel] => http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#uploader
                                                [type] => application/atom+xml
                                                [href] => http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/yLF5zO6ghZcOXKHRWTipvw?v=2
                                            )

                                        [4] => Array
                                            (
                                                [rel] => self
                                                [type] => application/atom+xml
                                                [href] => http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/dS4JR0BbKO8?v=2
                                            )

                                    )

                                [author] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => Drupalize.Me
                                                [uri] => http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Lullabot
                                                [yt$userId] => yLF5zO6ghZcOXKHRWTipvw
                                            )

                                    )

                                [yt$accessControl] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [action] => comment
                                                [permission] => allowed
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [action] => commentVote
                                                [permission] => allowed
                                            )

                                        [2] => Array
                                            (
                                                [action] => videoRespond
                                                [permission] => moderated
                                            )

                                        [3] => Array
                                            (
                                                [action] => rate
                                                [permission] => allowed
                                            )

                                        [4] => Array
                                            (
                                                [action] => embed
                                                [permission] => allowed
                                            )

                                        [5] => Array
                                            (
                                                [action] => list
                                                [permission] => allowed
                                            )

                                        [6] => Array
                                            (
                                                [action] => autoPlay
                                                [permission] => allowed
                                            )

                                        [7] => Array
                                            (
                                                [action] => syndicate
                                                [permission] => allowed
                                            )

                                    )

                                [gd$comments] => Array
                                    (
                                        [gd$feedLink] => Array
                                            (
                                                [rel] => http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comments
                                                [href] => http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/dS4JR0BbKO8/comments?v=2
                                                [countHint] => 17
                                            )

                                    )

                                [media$group] => Array
                                    (
                                        [media$category] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Tech
                                            )

                                        [media$content] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [url] => http://www.youtube.com/v/dS4JR0BbKO8?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata
                                                        [type] => application/x-shockwave-flash
                                                        [medium] => video
                                                        [isDefault] => true
                                                        [expression] => full
                                                        [duration] => 1153
                                                        [yt$format] => 5
                                                    )

                                                [1] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [url] => rtsp://r3---sn-5hn7su7k.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQnvKFtARwkudRMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
                                                        [type] => video/3gpp
                                                        [medium] => video
                                                        [expression] => full
                                                        [duration] => 1153
                                                        [yt$format] => 1
                                                    )

                                                [2] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [url] => rtsp://r3---sn-5hn7su7k.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQnvKFtARwkudRMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
                                                        [type] => video/3gpp
                                                        [medium] => video
                                                        [expression] => full
                                                        [duration] => 1153
                                                        [yt$format] => 6
                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [media$credit] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => lullabot
                                            )

                                        [media$description] => Discover hundreds more Drupal tutorial videos at Drupalize.Me/Videos.
```

I tried the code below but it doesn't work.

```
    <?php print $content['field_video_url]']['#formatter'][0]['#url'];?>
```

I had looked at his link but I'm not really understanding how it is working for him https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282194/drupal-7-calling-video-embed-field-from-template-file

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not trying to do anything fancy, and it is a module-provided video field, Drupal's `render` function should be enough:

```
<?php print render($content['field_video_url']);?>
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately this doesn't work

Comment: @amara "doesn't work" is most useless report in IT. It caused syntax error? Runtime error? Watchdog report? Died silently? Does is thow your field if you directly `print render($content);`?

Comment: sorry about the lack of details. It doesn't show anything on the front page when I render ($content['field_video_url']). When I go to the back-end this message error is coming "Notice: Undefined index: field_video_url] in include()" However it does show the video when I do print render($content);

Comment: Update:I'm not sure how, maybe issue with the cache but after writting print render($content), I then could see the video while writing this code <?php print render($content['field_video_url]']);?>. So it works thank you for your help!

Comment: @amara cache issues are burden we all need live with :)